# How to log an ALS model within a mlflow run?

Tags: save, databricks, pipeline, mlflow, als

I currently work on a databricks cluster trying to log an ALS model within a mlflow run.
Trying multiple different approaches I either get a TypeError "cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object" stopping my run or an OSError "No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpxiznhskj/sparkml'" not stopping my run but I am not able to load that model back into my code.

Here is the prep code to play around a little bit:

```
import mlflow
import logging
from pyspark.ml.evaluation import RegressionEvaluator
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf

data = [{"User": 1, "Item": 1, "Rating": 1},
        {"User": 2, "Item": 2, "Rating": 3},
        {"User": 3, "Item": 3, "Rating": 1},
        {"User": 4, "Item": 2, "Rating": 4},
        {"User": 1, "Item": 2, "Rating": 3},
        {"User": 2, "Item": 3, "Rating": 2},
        {"User": 2, "Item": 4, "Rating": 1},
        {"User": 4, "Item": 1, "Rating": 5}
        ]

conf = SparkConf().setAppName("ALS-mlflow-test")
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf)
rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
df_rating = rdd.toDF()

(df_train, df_test) = df_rating.randomSplit([0.8, 0.2])

logging.getLogger("mlflow").setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

1. Using this as a base I tried different approaches, starting with the mlflow.sklearn.log_model method:

```
with mlflow.start_run() as run:    
    model_als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="User", itemCol="Item", ratingCol="Rating", implicitPrefs=False,
          coldStartStrategy="drop")
    
    model_als.fit(df_train)
    mlflow.sklearn.log_model(model_als, artifact_path="test")
```

which results in the following error:

_SklearnCustomModelPicklingError: Pickling custom sklearn model ALS failed when saving model: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

2. Next I tried using a WrapperModel for my ALS model (the Wrapper does not actually do something yet):

```
class MyModel(mlflow.pyfunc.PythonModel):
    def __init__(self, model):
        self.model = model
    
    def predict(self, context, model_input):
        return self.my_custom_function(model_input)

    def my_custom_function(self, model_input):
        return 0

with mlflow.start_run():
    model_als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="User", itemCol="Item", ratingCol="Rating", implicitPrefs=False,
          coldStartStrategy="drop")
    my_model = MyModel(model_als)
    model_info = mlflow.pyfunc.log_model(artifact_path="model", python_model=my_model)
```

resulting in a more general but basically the same error as in step 1:

TypeError: cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object

3. I then tried putting my model within a pipeline (again nothing fancy just plain and simple for a test):

```
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline

with mlflow.start_run() as run:    
    model_als = ALS(maxIter=5, regParam=0.01, userCol="User", itemCol="Item", ratingCol="Rating", implicitPrefs=False,
          coldStartStrategy="drop")
    
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[model_als])
    pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(df_train)
    mlflow.spark.log_model(pipeline_model, artifact_path="test-pipeline")
```

This time the code executed but having a look at the debug log there also went something wrong:

```
stderr: Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
2023/01/05 08:54:22 INFO mlflow.spark: File '/tmp/tmpxiznhskj/sparkml' not found on DFS. Will attempt to upload the file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/utils/_capture_modules.py", line 162, in <module>
    main()
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/utils/_capture_modules.py", line 137, in main
    mlflow.pyfunc.load_model(model_path)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/pyfunc/__init__.py", line 484, in load_model
    model_impl = importlib.import_module(conf[MAIN])._load_pyfunc(data_path)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/utils/_capture_modules.py", line 134, in _load_pyfunc_patch
    return original(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/spark.py", line 832, in _load_pyfunc
    return _PyFuncModelWrapper(spark, _load_model(model_uri=path))
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/spark.py", line 727, in _load_model
    model_uri = _HadoopFileSystem.maybe_copy_from_uri(model_uri, dfs_tmpdir)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/spark.py", line 404, in maybe_copy_from_uri
    return cls.maybe_copy_from_local_file(_download_artifact_from_uri(src_uri), dst_path)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/tracking/artifact_utils.py", line 100, in _download_artifact_from_uri
    return get_artifact_repository(artifact_uri=root_uri).download_artifacts(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mlflow/store/artifact/local_artifact_repo.py", line 79, in download_artifacts
    raise IOError("No such file or directory: '{}'".format(local_artifact_path))
OSError: No such file or directory: '/tmp/tmpxiznhskj/sparkml'
```

4. Nevertheless, I tried loading the model, since the code ran through:

```
from pyspark.ml import PipelineModel

logged_model = 'runs:/xyz123/test'

# Load model
loaded_model = PipelineModel.load(logged_model)
```

results in the error:

org.apache.hadoop.fs.UnsupportedFileSystemException: No FileSystem for scheme "runs"

5. I then tried the auto generated code from databricks:

```
import mlflow
logged_model = 'runs:/xyz123/test'

# Load model
loaded_model = mlflow.spark.load_model(logged_model)

# Perform inference via model.transform()
loaded_model.transform(data)
```

results in the following error:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '_jdf'

6. Last piece of code would be (but was not able to get to it yet, since I can't load the model):

```
evaluator = RegressionEvaluator(metricName="rmse", labelCol="Rating", predictionCol="prediction")

df_pred = loaded_model.transform(df_test)
rmse = evaluator.evaluate(df_pred)

df_pred.display()

print("Root-mean-square error explicit = " + str(rmse))

user_recs = loaded_model.recommendForAllUsers(2)
user_recs.display()
```

---

I conclusion what I am trying to achieve is simply logging the provided ALS model within my mlflow run.
I ran out of ideas what could be wrong or what else I could try

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of MLFlow 2.1.1 `pyspark.ml.recommendation.ALS` is not on the [allowlist](https://mlflow.org/docs/latest/python_api/mlflow.pyspark.ml.html?highlight=spark%20pipeline#:%7E:text=The%20default%20log%20model%20allowlist%20in%20mlflow). Using the pipeline as you tested in #3 is the appropriate way to log unsupported spark.ml models.

It looks like you might have hit an environment issue when logging your model, as I was able to get the following implementation working both on Databricks and locally.

### Log within run

```py
import mlflow
from mlflow.models.signature import infer_signature
from pyspark.ml import Pipeline
from pyspark.ml.recommendation import ALS

# get a bigger test split from your data
(df_train, df_test) = df_rating.randomSplit([0.6, 0.4])

with mlflow.start_run() as run:
    # initialize als model
    als = ALS(
        maxIter=5,
        regParam=0.01,
        userCol="User",
        itemCol="Item",
        ratingCol="Rating",
        implicitPrefs=False,
        coldStartStrategy="drop",
    )

    # build and fit pipeline
    pipeline = Pipeline(stages=[als])
    pipeline_model = pipeline.fit(df_train)

    # test predict and infer signature
    predictions = pipeline_model.transform(df_test)
    signature = infer_signature(df_train, predictions)

    # log model
    mlflow.spark.log_model(
        pipeline_model, artifact_path="spark-model", signature=signature
    )

    mlflow.end_run()
```

**Reload for inference**

On Databricks you need to first move the model from the experiment into the model registry. This can be done via the UI or with the following commands.

```py
# construct the model_uri from generated run_id and the set artifact_path
run_id = "2f9a5424b1f44435a9413a3e2762b8a9"
artifact_path = "spark-model"
model_uri = f"runs:/{run_id}/{artifact_path}"

# move the model into the registry
model_details = mlflow.register_model(model_uri=model_uri, name=model_name)

# load model
version = 1
model_uri = f"models:/{model_name}/{version}"
loaded_model = mlflow.spark.load_model(model_uri)

# test predict
loaded_model.transform(df_test).show()
```

```
+----+------+----+----------+
|Item|Rating|User|prediction|
+----+------+----+----------+
|   2|     3|   2| 1.0075595|
+----+------+----+----------+
```

### Log directly to registry

Alternatively, you can also log directly to the model registry.

```py
# log model
model_name="als-model"
mlflow.spark.log_model(
    pipeline_model, 
    artifact_path="spark-model",
    registered_model_name=model_name
)

# log model
version = 1
model_uri = f"models:/{model_name}/{version}"
loaded_model = mlflow.spark.load_model(model_uri)

# test predict
loaded_model.transform(df_test).show()
```

### Logging as custom pyfunc

I also tried wrapping the ALS model and the pipeline in a custom pyfunc  and in both cases I received the same exact error. I believe there is something unserializable with the ALS model that prevents this...

Comment: Great, that worked perfectly fine, thanks a lot!

I didn't know that I need to register the model first and then work with the registered model, I thought I could just work with the experiments as is. 
Also I didn't have the allowlist on my radar, but I thought that this could be an issue, thanks!